# How to reduce few minutes for current date in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, swift2

How can I  reduce `5` or `10` minutes from current time and then store it as date format in Swift 2.0 ?

```
let now = NSDate()
var reducedTime = ???? \\ Here I want 10 minutes reduced from current time.
```

If current time is  02:20:00, then `reducedTime` should be 02:10:00
How can I do this in a **simplest way** ???

Comment: Have you read the documentation - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-SW8 ?  Hint: adding a negative number is the same as subtraction

Comment: That was just the first link that Google through up. Since it is Cocoa foundation it makes no difference but I have changed the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use calendar method dateByAddingUnit and subtract 10 minutes fro the date.

```
let now = NSDate()

let reducedTime = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)?.dateByAddingUnit(.Minute, value: -10, toDate: now, options: NSCalendarOptions())
```

Comment: Or `dateByAddiTimeInterval`?

Comment: @Paulw11 I prefer working with calendar units

Comment: @Paulw11 This is a safer approach. Too many people naively use `dateByAddingTimeInterval` to add days and mistakenly think it's OK to add `60*60*24` seconds. For this case, either is probably OK, but this approach is better in general.

Comment: thanks perfect answer