# How to add an Int to a NSDate?

Tags: ios, swift, int, nsdate

I'm currently getting JSON data for a date in this format:

```
Date = "2016-07-21T18:32:24.347Z"
```

I need to be able to add an Int, or float that represents minutes (60 min total)

How can I do this?

Comment: Just convert your string to date and use calendar method dateByAddingUnit to add minutes to it.

Comment: I've never done that before, how do you do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30269467/2303865

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33025898/2303865

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - Converting JSON date to Swift compatible date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269378/swift-converting-json-date-to-swift-compatible-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are like a million different ways that you could do this but that is probably not what you are looking for here. The best way to play with these things would be in a playground that way you can see how the changes to your code effect the end result.

So first you need a function that can take a string as a parameter.

```
func dateFromJSON(dateString: String?) -> NSDate? {}
```

This Function will take in our `string` and return us a `NSDate`

Then we need a date formatter, There are many different ways you can format a date and you can check out the documentation on them here [NSDateFormatter Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/)

so here is an example of a formatter `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"` you can see pretty quickly that different parts refer to differnt peices of a date. IE the `yyyy` is for the year in this case will give us something like `2016`. If it were `yy` we would only get `16`.

Initialize the dateFormatter then apply our format.

You should also throw in some checks to make your code safe. So it should look like this.

```
func dateFromWebJSON(dateString: String?) -> NSDate? {
   guard let dateString = dateString else {
    return nil
   }
  let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
  let date = ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"].flatMap { (dateFormat: String) -> NSDate? in
    formatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
    return formatter.dateFromString(dateString)
    }.first

  assert(date != nil, "Failed to convert date")
  return date
}
```

so now we can call

```
let time = dateFromWebAPIString(date)
print(time) //  Jul 21, 2016, 12:32 PM
```

Now to add time you have to remember that 1 NSTimeInterval is 1 second. So do some basic math

```
let min = 60
let hr = 60 * min
```

then we can add as much time as you want

```
 let newTime = time?.dateByAddingTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(20 * min))
 print(newTime) //  "Jul 21, 2016, 12:52 PM"
```

20 min later. Hope this helps

Comment: This was very informative, better than anything else I found online, thanks for your help!

Comment: I have done it a ton and still have to look it up time to time. I'm glad it was helpful.